# windows phone: deserialise and store both json key and value to modal

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-7, windows-phone-8.1, json-deserialization

Hello guyzzzz i want to store both key and value in modal class...below is my json..

```
 {
  "Example": [
    {
      "Invoice": {
        "TFDGFF": " 200",
        "BF": " 200",
        "MD": "10",
        "EFM": " 12",
        "ATT": "4"
      },
      "TF": "200"
    },
    {
      "Invoice": {
        "DF": " 49",
        "DR": " 49",
        "KJ": "4",
        "LKIH": " 14",
        "KJGU": "4"
      },
      "DF": "49"
    }
```

please tell me how to deserialise this json so that i can store both key as well as value in modal class and how should be the design of modal class ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Invoice
{
    public string TF { get; set; }
    public string BF { get; set; }
    public string MD { get; set; }
    public string EFM { get; set; }
    public string ATT { get; set; }
    public string FPK { get; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
    public string TF { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Example> Example { get; set; }
}
```

Make use of [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/)

Now make use of newtonsoft package to deserialize your json

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(yourstring);
```

**For New JSON**

```
public class RootObject
        {
            public List<Example> Example { get; set; }
        }

        public class Example
        {
            public Dictionary<string, string> Invoice { get; set; }           
        }
```

And you call it using

```
string temp=@" { ""Example"": [ { ""Invoice"": { ""TFDGFF"": ""200"", ""BF"": ""200"", ""MD"": ""10"", ""EFM"": ""12"", ""ATT"": ""4"" }, ""TF"": ""200"" }, { ""Invoice"": { ""DF"": "" 49"", ""DR"": "" 49"", ""KJ"": ""4"", ""LKIH"": "" 14"", ""KJGU"": ""4"" }, ""DF"": ""49"" }]}";
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(temp);
```

**For new Question Regarding Bind**

```
for (int i = 0; i < obj.Example.Count(); i++)
                {
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in obj.Example[i].Invoice)
                    {
                        string temp3 = pair.Key;
                        string temp2 = pair.Value;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: @jenin : i know this already..this does not store keys of json...i am having dynamic keys in my json..so i need to also store keys in modal

Comment: Well the json that you provided does not have any dynamic data you can either make use of Newtonsoft automatic deserializer instead of your custom class or best method would be to make a Dictonary object and make use of its key value pair

Comment: @jenin : As my json data contains multiple "Invoice" key..how to store it in dictionary ??

Can you give me some example ??

Comment: you would need to provide me JSON by which you mean having multiple 
"Invoice" key which one is dynamic since in the json you provided all belong to predefined keys

Comment: this could be the json that i might get from server side..so the keys are depeneding on the parent "Invoice" . so in this scenario what can i do ?


{
  "Example": [
    {
      "Invoice": {
        "TFDGFF": " 200",
        "BF": " 200",
        "MD": "10",
        "EFM": " 12",
        "ATT": "4"
      },
      "TF": "200"
    },
    {
      "Invoice": {
        "DF": " 49",
        "DR": " 49",
        "KJ": "4",
        "LKIH": " 14",
        "KJGU": "4"
      },
      "DF": "49"
    }

Comment: how to bind this to xaml ?
like if we have static json we bind like {Binding TF}..
how we will binf dictionary to xaml ?

Comment: Thank you so much...its working fine...but how to attach dictionary<string1,string2> to xaml...i m doing like this <textblock text = "{Binding Invoice[0]}" but string1 is not getting attached to textblock...please help

Comment: Do you just want to show the first item? I am guessing Not.
    You would need to look into observablecollection/ CollectionView. Store your collection inside these and use these static resource to bind inside your XAML

Comment: no i want to show both key value at the xaml 
As <textblock text = "{Binding Key}"/> <textblock text = "{Binding Value}"/>

Comment: Why not show them inside a gridview/listview the static resource type collection/observable can be used in both case gridview or textblock. Trust me do some research on binding you will learn a lot.

Comment: I am beginner and i have already crossed deadline assigned by my boss...i dont have any other choice but to ask here  :-(

Comment: Since you want to show both create a custom class having string key and value variables. Create a list object of this. store your values inside this list. Now add a collectionview object in xaml set its source to this list. then you can add them to your textblocks